# Windows batch find and replace string in the new file creates the line no. How to avoid the line no coming in the new file?

Tags: batch-file

I have tried the script given below which was given in another stack overflow page

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=%1"
set "replace=%2"
set "textfile=Input.txt"
set "newfile=Output.txt"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
set "line=%%i"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
echo(!line!
endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile%  %textfile%
```

with the above i got the in the new file as below,

1:testestes
2:testest
3:testtest

i don't want the line no's  1: 2: like that in my batch file. I just need like below

testestes
testest
testtest

Comment: without a listing of what you have in `input.txt` and what you've defined as `search` and `replace`, it's difficult to tell. There seems to be nothing in what you've posted which would generate those line numbers, which are characteristic of applying `findstr` somewhere - but you've not shown that.

Comment: Add `set "line=!line:*:=!"` before `echo(!line!`

Comment: That resolved the line problem. Thanks